# Mongodb shell find to filter and extract embedded text data

Tags: mongodb, find

I would like to find and extract details from a "stringified" api call which is a field in mongo db document.

The field is like "apiData" field below (only in one long line) which contains both request Headers and a Response Body
as an embedded object - I've separated it out on lines to make it easier to read.

The keys and values are inside "escaped" quotes

a) Can I filter/find based on a selection of header and Response body information
Currently, I'm using a regex e.g. apiData : /5684830/

Is there anything better?

b) extract a selection of header and Response body information from the field string in Mongo by
using build functionality or some else in the mongodb shell v4

Currently, I am exporting the entire field and then processing it.
I was hoping there might be a better way within the mongodb shell.

e.g Example of extract fields/end result

```
{
    "Status Code" : "200 OK"
     "numFound\": "56047",
     "ebook_count_i": 14,
}
```

Example of document

```
{
_id : ObjectId("0000000000000000000000000")
apiData : {
  \"Request URL\": \"http://api-call-eg.org/search.json?q=1984\"
  \"Request Method\": \"GET\"
  \"Status Code\": \"200 OK\"
  \"Response Body\" : 
    {
     \"numFound\": \"56047\",
     \"start\": \"0\",
     \"docs\": [
      {
       \"cover_i\": \"5684830\",
       \"ebook_count_i\": 14,
       \"author_name\": [ \"Rand McNally\"],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I filter/find based on a selection of header and Response body information
> Currently, I'm using a regex e.g. apiData : /5684830/

The way you use regex is the perfect solution for the way you have stored your data

> extract a selection of header and Response body information from the field string in Mongo by using build functionality or some else in the mongodb shell v4

Unfortunately, you have string. So it's the only option.

But if you can store them as `field:value` in mongo, you can make use of beautiful aggregation framework where you can do many queries in time efficient manner.